# socket connect() returning 0 even after peer reset

Tags: ios, c, sockets, tcp, posix

I have an iPad app in which I'm creating and connecting a posix `socket`. Calls to `connect(...)` are not responding as expected when the remote device rejects the connection attempt.

A simplified example of how I'm creating and connecting the `socket`:

```
struct sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;

int socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(socket < 0)
{
  NSLog(@"socket create failed: %s", strerror(errno));
}
else if(inet_aton(mAddress, &server.sin_addr))
{
  server.sin_port = htons(mPortNumber);
  if(connect(socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1)
  {
    NSLog(@"connect() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"connect() succeeded");
  }
}
```

In most cases, the above example works: e.g. for a remote device (hereafter referred to as 'the server') which is accepting connections, `connect()` returns `0` as expected. For a non-existent address, `connect()` blocks for a while then returns `-1`, and `errno` is `ETIMEDOUT`.

From the docs, if the server rejects the connection attempt I would expect `connect()` to return `-1` and for `errno` to be `ECONNREFUSED` or perhaps `ECONNRESET`. Instead, `connect()` returns `0`.

I've WireSharked the TCP conversation multiple times and can confirm that only ever consists of two packets:

> Client (iPad) -> Server: `SYN, ACK`
>
> Server -> Client (iPad) : `RST, ACK`

**Why does connect return `0`?**

Update: Connecting to the same server from a different client, e.g. Qt on Windows (winsock?) or Mac OSX (also posix) works as expected: i.e `connect()` returns `-1`, `ECONNREFUSED`. This leads me to believe it's a problem with the iPad end rather than the server end.

Comment: "*... if the remote device rejects the connection attempt ...*" I'm not sure if `to reject` is a well defined action interms of tcp/ip connection setup, so you might like to elaborate on how you define it.

Comment: What I mean by a 'refused connection' is one with a TCP conversation like the one above, i.e. the client tries to `SYN` and the server replies with a `RST`. What terminology would you use to describe this?

Comment: No `SYN-ACK` from the Remote in repsonse to the iPad's SYN?

Comment: No, just the `RST, ACK`, as detailed above. I'll try and attach the full wireshark output if that would help?

Comment: Did you ever managed to get an `ECONNREFUSED`? For other or similar scenarios?

Comment: Yes, see the update to the question (thanks for the continued help here, btw :)

Comment: I did not dare to mention this, but there definitely seems something to be broken in the iPad. Getting an immediate `RST` for a `SYN` should lead to `ECONNREFUSED` on the client side.

Comment: Agreed, that's what I would expect to see. Not sure I agree with yout the iPad is broken though! Much more likely to be something I'm doing, but thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: To be clear, when the server is listening the iPad can connect *and* exchange data correctly?

Comment: Yes, in most situations everything works absolutely fine. The code in question is pretty mature, and it's only recently that this situation has come to light.

Comment: You did wireshared this more than once? There never were no `FIN`s involved, no matter from which side?

Comment: Yes, it's the same every time, never any `FIN`s, just the two packets detailed above.

Comment: Just out of the blue: Which value had `socket` in these "strange" cases?

Comment: A range of positive integers, nothing unusual... Why do you ask?

Comment: So it's been none of the magic three: 0, 1 or 2? ;-) Another possiblity: Does the app go multithreading and perhaps accesss the same **numerical** socket descriptor concurrently?

Comment: Tcp connect is look like this:
Client: SYN
Server: SYN,ACK
Client: ACK
So SYN,ACK is sent by RESPONDER. How do you force to send it by INITIATOR?

Comment: What happens if you take the return value of connect() at face value und start writing data to the socket?  Do the syscalls succeed?  What does wireshark say?

Comment: Are you sure connect() returns 0? Because all you can infer from the code you've posted is it doesn't return -1, so in principle it might as well return -2.

Comment: As artistoex said, you don't know the return value. Check it explicitly. Another thing, I was taught to always do something like this bzero(&server, sizeof(server)) before using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create the socket like this, note the third parameter.

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

At the end of the day, it really does not matter that connect() returns 0 for rejected connection. Consider this: Let's say connect() succeeds, tcp connection is established and call returns 0. However, server immediately resets or disconnects before your code has change to call write or read on the socket. The next write fails with EPIPE and read returns 0.
You need to handle this case anyway.

I assume you've read this, but note that are more caveats in using POSIX sockets in iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html